# Changing Android SDK Location - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010

I want to change Android SDK Location from `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk` to `C:\Android\android-sdk`.  But whenever I change and save the solution => close VS and restart and load the solution android sdk location gets reset to `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk`